# Remove an array from list

Tags: c#

Hello I am having a simple question. When I try to remove array from list of arrays like:

```
var mock = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
var list = new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 } };
list.Remove(mock);
```

Value is still in array, what could be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because `int[]` is a **reference type** and not value type so basically `mock` and `list[0]` are not the same.

What you can do is to use `RemoveAll` to specify a predicate that will use `SequenceEquals` to find all those inner arrays that all the items are equal:

```
var mock = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
var list = new List<byte[]> 
{ 
    new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 }, 
    new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 } 
};

list.RemoveAll(item => mock.SequenceEqual(item));
```

The `SequenceEqual` will check that all the items of the 2 arrays are `Equal` - here too it matters if it is value or reference type, but in your case with value types it will work. If the inner items were a reference type you'd have to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`

---

If you do want to use `Remove`, now after we understood that we have to specify the same object (and it is a reference type) then use `FirstOrDefault` and then on that result use the `Remove`:

```
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(item => mock.SequenceEqual(item));
if(result != null)
{
    list.Remove(result);
}
```

Comment: @Wojciech Szabowicz - Did this help you understand and solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 arrays with the same value. `.Remove` goes by reference, not value.

```
var mock = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
var mock2 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
mock === mock2; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the object you are removing is not the same as the one in the list, although the values are the same. Try this and you´ll see it works fine:

```
var mock = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
var list = new List<byte[]> { {mock} };
list.Remove(mock);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the array by reference. If you want to remove an array that is equal, you have to check for sequence similarity:

```
list.RemoveAll(e => e.SequenceEqual(mock));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two object references, and they are not the same. You need to compare the byte array contents.
 You have to use **SequenceEqual** in c# (3.5 orhigher)

> bool equal = Array1.SequenceEqual(Array2);

Its requires Linq implementation.

> list.RemoveAll(x=> mock.SequenceEqual(x));

Please refer the following MSDN link
[MSDN - SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)